# Get URL of RSS Feed "Enclosure URL" tag in PHP

Tags: php, rss

The description works, but The URL does not work , nothing is displayed. I want to display the link, something like:

```
<enclosure url="http://example.com/file.mp3" length="123456789" type="audio/mpeg">
```

The code I have is:

```
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('feedlink example');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'url' =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure url')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 1;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
        $url = $feed[$x]['enclosure url'];
        echo '<div class="descricao">'.$description.'</div>'; //it works
        echo $url;  //it does not work , nothing is displayed
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving the correct name of the attribute.

For such tag as

```
<enclosure url="http://example.com/file.mp3" length="123456789" type="audio/mpeg">
```

`enclosure` is the tag (element name), whereas `url`, `length` and `type` are attributes.

A node with name `enclosure url` does not exist. You can get the elements with `$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')` and the value of url by calling `getAttribute('url')` on them.

For the method's documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php